# Load on a generator

Tags: power, generator

I am really stuck on this and I couldn't find any references on the internet regarding this. When a load is connected to a generator, why does the current withdrawn from the generator increases. Since the connected load will increase the overall impedance of the system, shouldn't the generator now supply less current ?

I was able to explain this in case of induction motors (When they are loaded, their effective reactance decreases and hence they draw more current), however I'm not able to explain this in cases of heaters and light bulbs.

Comment: How much impedance does an open circuit have?

Comment: An open circuit has infinite impedance

Comment: So then how does adding a load increase the impedance?

Comment: Ok now you're tricking me :P Let's say there was some load before hand, and more load is added to it :)

Comment: Okay, same question.

Comment: Well when you add load, you are increasing the impedance

Comment: Are you putting the loads in series?

Comment: As told to me by the interviewer, it doesn't matter to the generator if you're putting the load in series or parallel, because in real world, all loads are just a combination the the two. I made the same argument which you're going to make (Loads in parallel, leads to smaller impedance)

Comment: Perhaps you should be glad if you don't get that job...

Comment: So seriously, the argument should be just because the loads are added in parallel?? I mean I couldn't find this anywhere on the internet.

Comment: If you put two subcircuits in series with a supply, the supply doesn't have two loads. It has one load whose characteristics are a composite of the characteristics of the two subcircuits.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth remembering that a generator has an *active control system* that works to maintain a certain output voltage.

That is, the generator is responsive to changes in the load impedance. A step increase in load power requirement will cause a *temporary* voltage dip, as the output power of the generator at that instant is less than the amount of power required by the load.

However, within a period of five seconds, the generator's governor and automatic voltage regulator will act to increase the generator's power output (voltage, current) until it matches the amount of power (voltage, current) required by the loads.

Answer (score 1):

An unloaded generator will generate zero current, since it is open circuit. Hence there is no load angle. The load has infinite Z = no current draw.

In the case of induction motors, the current increase due to loading, is due to increase in the slip between rotor and stator (synch speed-rotor speed).

Heaters and lightbulbs are likely to be *fairly* resistive, probably *slightly* inductive.

Adding another element in parallel with a load like this may not change the Cos Phi all that much, and if the elements resistance is already quite high, you may not see any difference in current drawn.

To be any real help, we'd need to know the phase angle of your loads.